# How to group and count elements in a sublist using java streams

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping, counting

I want to group and count elements in a sub list using java streams.

For Example, I have an answer of type AnswerWithOneCorrectOption which looks like:

```
class AnswerWithOneCorrectOption {
     Long choiceId;
}
```

This answer type has only one correct option and is stored in "AnswerWithOneCorrectOption.id". I am streaming through a list of AnswerWithOneCorrectOption's, grouping based on id and counting using:

```
private Map<Long, Long> countChoicesAndGroup(List<AnswerWithOneCorrectOption> answers){

Map<Long, Long> map = answers.parallelStream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AnswerWithOneCorrectOption::getChoiceId, 
 Collectors.counting())); 

 return map;
}
```

Suppose I have another answer type that can have multiple correct options. I am saving those options in `List<Long> choiceIds`.

```
class AnswerWithMultipleCorrectOptions {
     List<Long> choiceIds;
}
```

How can I group by choiceId's in `List<Long> choiceIds` and count?

Comment: I don't understand how you want to find "multiple" options.  Do you mean instead of `getId` you want to check against the entire list of `ids` for a correct answer?  How does that work, can you show us with a loop instead of a stream?

Comment: Can you show some sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: Yeah. If user chose only one option, it will be saved in answer.id. If he chooses more than one answer, I will add it to the list answer.ids. The code I mentioned in question works for answer.id. How can I group and count if I have answer.ids instead of answer.id?

Comment: Is it possible that `id` is duplicated in `ids`? In other words, is `id` always different from all the answers in `ids` or might it be included in the list of `ids`?  (BTW this is terrible design.  It would be better to just have a list of answers, and if the user chooses just one then the length of the list is 1.)

Comment: What type of map do you expect ?

Comment: @Ruslan `groupingBy` and `groupingByConcurrent` don't specify what type of map they return.  `Map<Long,Long>` is a close as we can get.

Comment: @markspace I mean OP can group by `Answer::getIds()` that lead to `Map<List<Long>, Long>`

Comment: I updated the question with more detail. @Ruslan Yeah I can get Map<List<Long>, Long> using Answer::getIds(). Is there any way I can get Map<Long,Long> by grouping and counting elements in the sub list?

Comment: OK, now you do you want to determine a correct answer?  It seems that you only get the answer, never determine if it is "correct" or not.  I'm leaning towards `flatmap` right now.  You could turn your list of answers into a flat stream like you had in the first example and get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If user chose only one option, it will be saved in answer.id. If he chooses more than one answer, I will add it to the list answer.ids.

It is probably better to use `Answer` with `List<Long> ids` only. And in case of user chose only one option you will just have list with one element. It is allowing you to grouping by answer (don't forget about equals/hashcode) both cases:

```
Map<Answer, Long> collect = answers.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));
```

But if you want to group by `List<Long>` it can be done the same way:

```
Map<List<Long>, Long> collect = answers.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Answer::choiceIds, counting()));
```

**Update**: to group by elements in the sub list you can use `flatMap` before:

```
Map<Long, Long> map = answers.stream()
        .flatMap(answer -> answer.getIds().stream())
        .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));
```

Comment: I can get Map<List<Long>, Long> using Answer::getIds(). Is there any way I can get Map<Long,Long> by grouping and counting elements in the sub list?

Comment: That did it. Thanks @Rusian